# using ruby threads with delay

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have written a ruby script which contains the list of files(~250) to be downloaded. Since sequential download will take ages. I thought of downloading each file in a separate thread. Even though I have given the delay of 20, it looks like all the threads are hitting the server at a time. Hence I am getting 502 error and none of the files are downloaded. How can I download all the files parallelly without overloading the server.

```
#list of fiiles
files = []
threads = []  
files.each do |file|
   threads  << Thread.new(file){ | file |
     sleep(20)  
     #Download the file using either curb or Net::HTTP
     sleep(20)
}
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: Your threads all have the same delay and you start them all in once.

Comment: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using doing this in the background.

Check out some of the gems that actually dont block and do the things in background - eg., DelayedJob. Also, check out some of the railscasts :

[http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/128-starling-and-workling

Answer (score 0):

Create a Thread-pool from which new threads are created. This way, you will not create more than the ones provided in the pool and avoid crashing the app/server. Alternatively, take a look at [SideKiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) This is a multi-threaded alternative to background queue processors like DelayedJob and Resque.

Answer (score -1):

```
threads.each {|thread| thread.join; sleep 1}
```